# Arduino WebServer and socket.io

Tags: ajax, sockets, arduino

We're trying to send a continuous stream of data from the Arduino Uno to a web page using the official Arduino Wifi Shield. The Arduino is acting as the server, writing the web page markdown and sending the data from a pin. We need AJAX to have the data continuously update without refreshing the page - so we're using socket.io. We can write the client-side socket.io code onto the web page, but we need to be able to create the socket on the Arduino Uno as well.

We tried using the WebServer example, but that failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Base socket.io code below:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-type:text/html");

client.println();

//change updating 
client.print("<HEAD>");
client.print("<TITLE />3 Phase Relay</title>");
client.println("</head>");

client.println("<script src=\"/socket.io/socket.io.js\"></script>");
client.println("<script>");
client.println("var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.11.2');");
client.println("socket.on('news', function (data) {");
client.println("console.log(data);");
client.println("socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });");
client.println("});");
client.println("</script>");

// the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
client.print("Peak Voltage Reading: ");
client.println(peak);
client.print("Phase Time Reading: ");
client.println(phasetime);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a classic example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask for help on a solution that is not necessarily solving your original problem, without telling more about what your original problem is…

Because your problem is that you make a wrong assumption for your problem:

> […] We need AJAX to have the data continuously update without refreshing the page - so we're using socket.io […]

you want to have the data updated continuously, so you want AJAX updates. Using `socket.io` is not a consequence of using AJAX, though it needs AJAX to run. But `socket.io` also needs long polling sockets, which I really doubt is implemented in the arduino webserver, because it'd need at least to have an implementation of something like [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) which is not likely to happen on a system that does not have the concept of a file descriptor. I'm not even talking about the fact that the Arduino Uno's [Atmega328](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx) has only 2k of RAM, which makes it really hard to have it serve multiple long-polling clients.

So if you insist on using socket.io, you may want to reverse the way it works, by using a proxy webserver to which your arduino connects to and sends updates to, using an [arduino socket.io client](https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client%E2%80%8E). Though it'd be as easy to just call a webserver page with your updates as GET/POST parameters, as then you'd have to run some server-side code.

In the end, you may prefer to use another way of mimicking the long-polling without actually doing long-polling in your AJAX requests. The most efficient way of doing it would be to use a JSON based polling communication technique, which basic principles are:

- buffer all data to be sent in your memory (ram or external) indexed with timestamps ;

  - I'd use a circular buffer, and if the dataset can get really big I'd use an external flash memory ;
- when the client sends a request, ask for the timestamp or the id of the last update (or `0`) ;
- if there are updates:

  - send back as a JSON the events/values you want to send back
- else

  - return an empty value or a [HTTP 304 not modified status](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.5)

For the timestamps, just use the date since the arduino has been started, but be careful that if it run more than 50 days, it will overflow. It should'nt be a big deal, but still it has to be taken into account.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/sfentress/2126328) you can find an implementation of a webserver serving JSONP content. It's still up to you to implement the handling of the timestamps and your data buffer, which will suit your needs at best.